# How can I create Custom Action through Installshield which calls a WiX Custom Action taking a string parameter?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

Is it possible for Installshield to run a WiX Custom Action which takes an additional parameter other than the required Session parameter? For example:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session, string param)
{
  session.Log(param);
  return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

(note the second parameter)

I am creating a Type 1 custom action through Installshield 2012. It takes a Function Name and I see no way to add parameter. **I guess I'm hoping for a hack here, so if there is an unsupported mechanism through the MSI database, please share**.

I was able to with Installshield Interop, and even being limited to string parameters, it allowed for a great solution of binary re-use of the across my installation projects, where the installation project was in control of specific parameters, rather than the custom action code itself.

Comment: Type 1 custom actions take a pointer to an msi handle (hMSI) as an argument.  WiX DTF CA's have a native stub that take this and then invoke .NET.  The Session class is an encapsulation of this.  See my blog for more information. http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-managed.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to pass extra parameters to the custom action method. It is called by the Windows Installer, and it seems reasonable that it expects a well-defined signature.

However, you can work it around. If you need to pass some data to the custom action, you can use the `Session` object for this.

If your custom action is immediate, you can address the MSI properties in your custom action code like this:

```
session["PROPERTYNAME"] = "some value";
```

In immediate custom action the `session` object can address any property from the property table.

If you custom action is deferred, there's a mechanism to pass the necessary data into it. You should author a usual immediate "set-a-property" custom action and pass the necessary data to the property called like the name of your deferred CA. The sample is usually much more clear than shaping it into words:

```
<!-- This is a subsidiary CA, note the property name is equal to the deferred CA name -->
<CustomAction Id="SetForMyDeferredCA" Return="check" Property="MyDeferredCA" Value="source=[SourceFolder];target=[TargetFolder]"/>
<!-- And this is the deferred CA which does the job -->
<CustomAction Id="MyDeferredCA" Return="asyncWait" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="MyMethodName" />
```

And inside the deferred CA you can address the passed data like this:

```
var source = session.CustomActionData["source"];
var target = session.CustomActionData["target"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct. You can't. It's by design.